# uninitialized constant Buyer (NameError) Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand why I keep getting the error

> uninitialized constant Buyer (NameError)

When I created the subclass `Buyer`, i tried to run `puts buyer1.run` and it isn't working. I don't understand what I am doing wrong when trying to make a subclass to the parent class.

```
class User

  def initialize(name)
     @name = name
  end

  def run
    puts "i am running"
  end

  class Buyer < User
  end

  def get_name
    @name
  end


end

user = User.new("mike")
buyer1 = Buyer.new("jack")
puts buyer1.run
puts user.get_name
puts user.run
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Buyer` class is defined inside `User` class (which is weird, but lets you use `get_name` method for `User` instances):

```
buyer1 = User::Buyer.new("jack")
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/Bylr)

Comment: STI subclasses should live on their own, not buried inside another. Having them in odd places will confuse the autoloader. At the very least this should be in `user/buyer.rb`, but even better is to have it at the root, simply `buyer.rb` in `models`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User

  def initialize(name)
     @name = name
  end

  def run
    puts "i am running"
  end

  class Buyer < User
  end

  def get_name
    @name
  end

end

class Buyer < User 
  # instantiate the Buyer class outside of the User class
end

user = User.new("mike")
buyer1 = Buyer.new("jack")
puts buyer1.run
puts user.get_name
puts user.run
```

While potashins answer is informative the above change to your code will help you more accurately understand what your doing here with inheritance.

Instantiate the Buyer class outside of the User class and inherit User with < User etc.